# How to use LINQ filter on a DataTable in Uipath

Tags: c#, linq, uipath, uipath-studio

I have a `Linq` query written in **C#.** I don't know how to change it so that it works with `UiPath`.

The query `finds all` *AccountNumber* in the table and finds the *sum of Remainder rows*

```cs
var afterChange = listDate.GroupBy(account => account.AccountNumber)
   .Select(group => new 
   {
      AccountNumber = group.Key,
      Сurrency = group.Select(groupElement => groupElement.Сurrency).First(),
      Remainder = group.Select(groupElement => groupElement.Remainder).Sum(),
   })
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(x => new TableData 
   {
      Remainder = x.Remainder,
      AccountNumber = x.AccountNumber,
      Сurrency = x.Сurrency
   })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: So what about Currency? How it is retrieved is not a good way.

Comment: Currency is the same everywhere, you can simply copy it into the final table

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with UiPath, but your query needs correction.

```cs
var afterChange = listDate.GroupBy(account => new { account.AccountNumber, account.Сurrency })
   .Select(group => new TableData
   {
      AccountNumber = group.Key.AccountNumber,
      Сurrency = group.Key.Сurrency,
      Remainder = group.Sum(x => x.Remainder),
   })
   .ToList();
```